# Nhibernate fluent ignore property while updating with condition

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I update an entity and ignore some its properties in case their values are null (in the updated entity), with NHibernate?
If the property value is not null, it should be included in the update.

Example, with an entity having an `Id` and a `Name`:

- If the name is null we update the entity without the name.
- If the name is not null we update the entity with the name.

Comment: Did you try something before yourself? This platform is meant to help you create, not to create for you.

Comment: If the name column is nullable, you will get this functionality out of the box. Or have I missed the point of your question?

Comment: Sure i tried something before, but i couldnt find anything on website

Comment: David i didnt meant to this. I meant in the mapping you define that if the value is null its not update the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things for doing that:

- Enable [dynamic updates](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class). By default, NHibernate prepares for each entity an update query updating all columns but the primary key. And when updating the entity, it uses it by specifying all values, including those having not changed. So you need to tell NHibernate to use dynamic updates, where it generates an ad-hoc update query at each update for updating only changed properties.
  With hbm, you have to put `dynamic-update="true"` on your class mapping. There is likely some adequate class mapping method to call for this in fluent.
- Use an [interceptor](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html#objectstate-interceptors) or an [event](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html#objectstate-events) for customizing the dirtiness check algorithm. There are a bunch of answers about that on Stack Overflow, like [this one](/a/5091731/1178314) and this [other one (from me)](/a/36435606/1178314).
  They are not about your requirements, but adapting them should not be hard.

Comment: If i understand you right i need to call the db for the interception so its mean i am retrieving the data from the db before i update. Is there any way i can do it without retreiving the entity from the db?

Comment: @ItayGolan, you do not have to do it explicitly, NHibernate will do it for you when calling `ISession.Update()` on a detached entity. (If you have already loaded the entity in the session then try to update it with a detached version, use `Merge` instead.) If you do not want NHibernate to load the entity for updating it, you may use a [tag:hql] update query as explained [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html#batch-direct). But that is not an usual pattern for using an ORM.